# SMTP Error 503 - All RCPT commands were rejected

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, cpanel

I'm trying to host multiple Laravel applications on cPanel and I have been facing this issue for the past 3 days:

```
503-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.  (domain.com)
503-[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:XXXXX is not permitted to relay through this server
503-without authentication.
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
```

The websites are currently hosted on a server that runs CentOS 7 with WHM cPanel. The mail are sent via SMTP Relay using Microsoft Exchange Server.

This is the current email configuration that I'm using in Laravel:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=host.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="info@domain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example"
```

The steps that I have tried:

- Tried sending mail via Laravel's Tinker using `Mail::raw()` and it works. Weird but still don't understand how does that work.
- Able to send emails via `telnet`

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing some steps here and I'd be glad if anyone can point it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says, that your server is not allowed to relay through the remote server without authentication.
In your config, no username or password is set, so you don't authenticate.

Just add the needed bits and do authenticate to the server (or change the settings of the server, so you can relay without auth. But I wouldn't recommend that)